# Spaces inbetween HTML elements in Nokogiri::HTML#content

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

When I run this

```
Nokogiri::HTML('<div class="content"><p>Hello</p><p>Good Sir</p></div>').content
```

I get this

```
"HelloGood Sir"
```

Is there a way to get the following with Nokogiri's API?

```
"Hello Good Sir"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div class="content"><p>Hello</p><p>Good Sir</p></div>')

# below will fetch all text nodes irrespective of any tag,from the current document.
doc.xpath("//text()").map(&:text)
# => ["Hello", "Good Sir"]

doc.xpath("//text()").map(&:text).join(" ")
# => "Hello Good Sir"

# below will fetch all text nodes which are wrapped inside the p tag,
# from the current document.
doc.xpath("//p").map(&:text)
# => ["Hello", "Good Sir"]

doc.xpath("//p").map(&:text).join(" ")
# => "Hello Good Sir"
```

Comment: both answers are great, I went with this one b/c it doesn't require knowledge of nested html tags. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Like Arup pointed out

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div class="content"><p>Hello</p><p>Good Sir</p></div>')
doc.css('p').map(&:text).join(" ") #=> "Hello Good Sir"
```